# Problem with find function in VBA error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently the trying to now if a value exist or not in the "B:B" range. for this i've using the following code:

```
code=range("B:B").find("the value I look for")
```

This is supposed to give me the answer "Nothing" if the value is not found, but instead it gives me the error 91 "error 91 object variable or with block not set".

this was my idea when I started:

if code = Nothing then
msgbox "the value does not exist"
exit sub
else
end if

I would really apreciate your help!

Comment: You forgot the `Set`: `Set code = ...`

Comment: waht do you mean?
     set code = range("B:B")
    code.find("value")

Comment: `Range.Find` returns a `Range` object. So `Dim foundCell As Range`, `Set foundCell = range("B:B").Find("the value I look for")`, then `If foundCell Is Nothing Then`....

Comment: You can probably use `Application.CountIf` or `Application.Match` for this too... perhaps easier.

Comment: i tried Application.Match, but it had the same 91 error problem, thats why i tried with the find function:
``Dim foundcell As Range
Set foundcell = Range("B:B").Application.Match("my value")``

Comment: `Dim CurrentMatch As Variant` `CurrentMatch = Application.Match("my value", Range("B:B"), 0)` `If IsNumeric(CurrentMatch) Then` `MsgBox "Value found."` `Else` `MsgBox "Value not found."` `End If`